# Using WebClient to load HTML

Tags: c#, webclient, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to download web page:

```
string remoteUri = "http://whois.domaintools.com/94.100.179.159";
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(remoteUri);
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(download);
doc.Save("file1.htm");
```

Having an error

> webexception was unhandled: (403) Forbidden.

Are there any other ways to download the page?
I've tried HtmlDocument class, but as i can see it needs loaded web page in the browser.

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
        string ip = "http://whois.domaintools.com/";
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(ip);

        foreach (HtmlNode link in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@name = 'description']"))
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (var myWebClient = new WebClient())
{
    myWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";

    string page = myWebClient.DownloadString("http://whois.domaintools.com/94.100.179.159");

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);
}
```

Comment: I've used this user-Agent, but still forbidden error - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1"

Comment: @fen1ksss just copy&paste above code. i tried it before posting................ And tested it once more. It works.

Comment: nope, still the same... i'm using virtual machine of windows xp, mb that's the key? i have mac os 10.7

Comment: works great for example with www.google.com, but my previous code works with google too..

Comment: are there a way to enter my login and password before?

Comment: `myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(...)`. Also try `myWebClient.Proxy=null`

Comment: nope... still the same problem... when i open browser and enter login and password, everything works great, but when i close browser, have Forbidden 403 error. Probably there is the way to enter login and password via c#??

Comment: @fen1ksss maybe you should use `webClient.UploadValues`

Answer (score 2):

The site simply returns an error when it finds no user agent in the request, here's the working code.

```
string remoteUri = "http://whois.domaintools.com/94.100.179.159";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
{
  myWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "some browser user agent");
  doc.Load(myWebClient.OpenRead(remoteUri));
}
doc.Save("file1.htm");
```

Or if you want to use `HtmlWeb`

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
hwObject.UserAgent = "some browser user agent";
//more code...
```

Comment: i've used this user-Agent, but still forbidden error - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.83 Safari/537.1"